# IMFSinkWriterCallback Never happens

Tags: ms-media-foundation

I'm trying to get my IMFSinkWriter's Finalize() call to be asynchronous.

So I created this

```
class MyMFSinkWriterCallback : public IMFSinkWriterCallback
{
public:
    MyMFSinkWriterCallback();
    virtual ~MyMFSinkWriterCallback();

    // IMFSinkWriterCallback methods
    STDMETHODIMP OnFinalize(HRESULT hrStatus);
    STDMETHODIMP OnMarker(DWORD dwStreamIndex, LPVOID pvContext);

    // IUnknown methods
    STDMETHODIMP QueryInterface(REFIID iid, void** ppv);
    STDMETHODIMP_(ULONG) AddRef();
    STDMETHODIMP_(ULONG) Release();

private:
    long m_nRefCount;
};

HRESULT MyMFSinkWriterCallback::OnFinalize(HRESULT hrStatus)
{
    OutputDebugStringA("MyMFSinkWriterCallback::OnFinalize\n");
    return S_OK;
}
```

And I installed it like this

```
hr = pAttributes->SetUnknown(MF_SINK_WRITER_ASYNC_CALLBACK, new MyMFSinkWriterCallback());

if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
    hr = MFCreateSinkWriterFromURL(L"C:\test.mp4", NULL, pAttributes, &MySinkWriter);
}
```

QueryInterface, AddRef, and Release are all being called but when I end my capture like this

```
OutputDebugStringA("MySinkWriter->Finalize START\n");
HRESULT hr = MySinkWriter->Finalize();
OutputDebugStringA("MySinkWriter->Finalize END\n");
```

All I see in my output log is

MySinkWriter->Finalize START

MySinkWriter->Finalize END

I never see

MyMFSinkWriterCallback::OnFinalize

Comment: Yes, that's what this line is hr = pAttributes->SetUnknown(MF_SINK_WRITER_ASYNC_CALLBACK, new MyMFSinkWriterCallback());

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you don't let time to "OnFinalize" to execute. Here is a working sample code (based on [Sink Writer Tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff819477(v=vs.85).aspx)) :

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <mfapi.h>
#include <mfidl.h>
#include <Mfreadwrite.h>
#include <mferror.h>
#include <Shlwapi.h>
#include <new>

#pragma comment(lib, "mfreadwrite")
#pragma comment(lib, "mfplat")
#pragma comment(lib, "mfuuid")
#pragma comment(lib, "Shlwapi")

template <class T> void SafeRelease(T **ppT){

    if(*ppT){
        (*ppT)->Release();
        *ppT = NULL;
    }
}

// Format constants
const UINT32 VIDEO_WIDTH = 640;
const UINT32 VIDEO_HEIGHT = 480;
const UINT32 VIDEO_FPS = 30;
const UINT64 VIDEO_FRAME_DURATION = 10 * 1000 * 1000 / VIDEO_FPS;
const UINT32 VIDEO_BIT_RATE = 800000;
const GUID   VIDEO_ENCODING_FORMAT = MFVideoFormat_WMV3;
const GUID   VIDEO_INPUT_FORMAT = MFVideoFormat_RGB32;
const UINT32 VIDEO_PELS = VIDEO_WIDTH * VIDEO_HEIGHT;
const UINT32 VIDEO_FRAME_COUNT = 20 * VIDEO_FPS;

// Buffer to hold the video frame data.
DWORD videoFrameBuffer[VIDEO_PELS];

class CMFSinkWriterCallback : public IMFSinkWriterCallback{

    public:

      CMFSinkWriterCallback(HANDLE hFinalizeEvent) : m_nRefCount(1), m_hFinalizeEvent(hFinalizeEvent){}
      virtual ~CMFSinkWriterCallback(){}

      // IMFSinkWriterCallback methods
      STDMETHODIMP OnFinalize(HRESULT hrStatus){

        OutputDebugString(L"CMFSinkWriterCallback::OnFinalize\n");

            if(m_hFinalizeEvent != NULL){
                SetEvent(m_hFinalizeEvent);
            }

            return hrStatus;
        }

      STDMETHODIMP OnMarker(DWORD dwStreamIndex, LPVOID pvContext){

        return S_OK;
      }

      // IUnknown methods
      STDMETHODIMP QueryInterface(REFIID riid, void** ppv){

        static const QITAB qit[] = {
            QITABENT(CMFSinkWriterCallback, IMFSinkWriterCallback),
            {0}
        };

        return QISearch(this, qit, riid, ppv);
      }

      STDMETHODIMP_(ULONG) AddRef(){

        return InterlockedIncrement(&m_nRefCount);
      }

      STDMETHODIMP_(ULONG) Release(){

        ULONG refCount = InterlockedDecrement(&m_nRefCount);

        if(refCount == 0){
            delete this;
        }

        return refCount;
      }

    private:

      volatile long m_nRefCount;
      HANDLE m_hFinalizeEvent;
};


HRESULT InitializeSinkWriter(IMFSinkWriter **ppWriter, DWORD *pStreamIndex, IMFSinkWriterCallback* pCallBack){

    *ppWriter = NULL;
    *pStreamIndex = NULL;

    IMFAttributes   *pAttributes = NULL;
    IMFSinkWriter   *pSinkWriter = NULL;
    IMFMediaType    *pMediaTypeOut = NULL;
    IMFMediaType    *pMediaTypeIn = NULL;
    DWORD           streamIndex = 0;

    // Create the empty attribute store.
    HRESULT hr = MFCreateAttributes(&pAttributes, 1);

    if(SUCCEEDED(hr)){
        hr = pAttributes->SetUnknown(MF_SINK_WRITER_ASYNC_CALLBACK, pCallBack);
    }

    if(SUCCEEDED(hr)){
        hr = MFCreateSinkWriterFromURL(L"output.wmv", NULL, pAttributes, &pSinkWriter);
    }

    // Set the output media type.
    if(SUCCEEDED(hr)){
        hr = MFCreateMediaType(&pMediaTypeOut);
    }

    if(SUCCEEDED(hr)){
        hr = pMediaTypeOut->SetGUID(MF_MT_MAJOR_TYPE, MFMediaType_Video);
    }

    if(SUCCEEDED(hr)){
        hr = pMediaTypeOut->SetGUID(MF_MT_SUBTYPE, VIDEO_ENCODING_FORMAT);
    }

    if(SUCCEEDED(hr)){
        hr = pMediaTypeOut->SetUINT32(MF_MT_AVG_BITRATE, VIDEO_BIT_RATE);
    }

    if(SUCCEEDED(hr)){
        hr = pMediaTypeOut->SetUINT32(MF_MT_INTERLACE_MODE, MFVideoInterlace_Progressive);
    }

    if(SUCCEEDED(hr)){
        hr = MFSetAttributeSize(pMediaTypeOut, MF_MT_FRAME_SIZE, VIDEO_WIDTH, VIDEO_HEIGHT);
    }

    if(SUCCEEDED(hr)){
        hr = MFSetAttributeRatio(pMediaTypeOut, MF_MT_FRAME_RATE, VIDEO_FPS, 1);
    }

    if(SUCCEEDED(hr)){
        hr = MFSetAttributeRatio(pMediaTypeOut, MF_MT_PIXEL_ASPECT_RATIO, 1, 1);
    }

    if(SUCCEEDED(hr)){
        hr = pSinkWriter->AddStream(pMediaTypeOut, &streamIndex);
    }

    // Set the input media type.
    if(SUCCEEDED(hr)){
        hr = MFCreateMediaType(&pMediaTypeIn);
    }

    if(SUCCEEDED(hr)){
        hr = pMediaTypeIn->SetGUID(MF_MT_MAJOR_TYPE, MFMediaType_Video);
    }

    if(SUCCEEDED(hr)){
        hr = pMediaTypeIn->SetGUID(MF_MT_SUBTYPE, VIDEO_INPUT_FORMAT);
    }

    if(SUCCEEDED(hr)){
        hr = pMediaTypeIn->SetUINT32(MF_MT_INTERLACE_MODE, MFVideoInterlace_Progressive);
    }

    if(SUCCEEDED(hr)){
        hr = MFSetAttributeSize(pMediaTypeIn, MF_MT_FRAME_SIZE, VIDEO_WIDTH, VIDEO_HEIGHT);
    }

    if(SUCCEEDED(hr)){
        hr = MFSetAttributeRatio(pMediaTypeIn, MF_MT_FRAME_RATE, VIDEO_FPS, 1);
    }

    if(SUCCEEDED(hr)){
        hr = MFSetAttributeRatio(pMediaTypeIn, MF_MT_PIXEL_ASPECT_RATIO, 1, 1);
    }

    if(SUCCEEDED(hr)){
        hr = pSinkWriter->SetInputMediaType(streamIndex, pMediaTypeIn, NULL);
    }

    // Tell the sink writer to start accepting data.
    if(SUCCEEDED(hr)){
        hr = pSinkWriter->BeginWriting();
    }

    // Return the pointer to the caller.
    if(SUCCEEDED(hr)){
        *ppWriter = pSinkWriter;
        (*ppWriter)->AddRef();
        *pStreamIndex = streamIndex;
    }

    SafeRelease(&pAttributes);
    SafeRelease(&pSinkWriter);
    SafeRelease(&pMediaTypeOut);
    SafeRelease(&pMediaTypeIn);

    return hr;
}

HRESULT WriteFrame(IMFSinkWriter *pWriter, DWORD streamIndex, const LONGLONG& rtStart){

    IMFSample *pSample = NULL;
    IMFMediaBuffer *pBuffer = NULL;

    const LONG cbWidth = 4 * VIDEO_WIDTH;
    const DWORD cbBuffer = cbWidth * VIDEO_HEIGHT;

    BYTE *pData = NULL;

    // Create a new memory buffer.
    HRESULT hr = MFCreateMemoryBuffer(cbBuffer, &pBuffer);

    // Lock the buffer and copy the video frame to the buffer.
    if(SUCCEEDED(hr)){
        hr = pBuffer->Lock(&pData, NULL, NULL);
    }

    if(SUCCEEDED(hr)){

        hr = MFCopyImage(pData, cbWidth, (BYTE*)videoFrameBuffer, cbWidth, cbWidth, VIDEO_HEIGHT);
    }

    if(pBuffer){
        pBuffer->Unlock();
    }

    // Set the data length of the buffer.
    if(SUCCEEDED(hr)){
        hr = pBuffer->SetCurrentLength(cbBuffer);
    }

    // Create a media sample and add the buffer to the sample.
    if(SUCCEEDED(hr)){
        hr = MFCreateSample(&pSample);
    }

    if(SUCCEEDED(hr)){
        hr = pSample->AddBuffer(pBuffer);
    }

    // Set the time stamp and the duration.
    if(SUCCEEDED(hr)){
        hr = pSample->SetSampleTime(rtStart);
    }

    if(SUCCEEDED(hr)){
        hr = pSample->SetSampleDuration(VIDEO_FRAME_DURATION);
    }

    // Send the sample to the Sink Writer.
    if(SUCCEEDED(hr)){
        hr = pWriter->WriteSample(streamIndex, pSample);
    }

    SafeRelease(&pSample);
    SafeRelease(&pBuffer);

    return hr;
}

void main(){

    HANDLE hFinalizeEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, FALSE, FALSE, NULL);

    if(hFinalizeEvent == NULL)
        return;

    // Set all pixels to green
    for(DWORD i = 0; i < VIDEO_PELS; ++i){
        videoFrameBuffer[i] = 0x000000FF;
    }

    HRESULT hr = CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED);

    if(SUCCEEDED(hr)){

        hr = MFStartup(MF_VERSION);

        if(SUCCEEDED(hr)){

            IMFSinkWriterCallback* pCallBack = NULL;
            IMFSinkWriter *pSinkWriter = NULL;
            DWORD stream;

            pCallBack = new (std::nothrow)CMFSinkWriterCallback(hFinalizeEvent);

            hr = pCallBack ? S_OK : E_POINTER;

            if(SUCCEEDED(hr)){
              hr = InitializeSinkWriter(&pSinkWriter, &stream, pCallBack);
            }

            if(SUCCEEDED(hr)){

                // Send frames to the sink writer.
                LONGLONG rtStart = 0;

                for(DWORD i = 0; i < VIDEO_FRAME_COUNT; ++i){

                    hr = WriteFrame(pSinkWriter, stream, rtStart);

                    if(FAILED(hr)){
                            break;
                    }

                    rtStart += VIDEO_FRAME_DURATION;
                }
            }

            if(SUCCEEDED(hr)){
                hr = pSinkWriter->Finalize();
                WaitForSingleObject(hFinalizeEvent, INFINITE);
            }

            SafeRelease(&pCallBack);
            SafeRelease(&pSinkWriter);
            MFShutdown();
        }

        CoUninitialize();
    }

    CloseHandle(hFinalizeEvent);
}
```